# ListView DeleteMethod not passing the DataKeyNames value

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a list view:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="NoteId" DeleteMethod="ListView1_DeleteItem" ItemType="NotesPractice.Note" SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData"
<ItemTemplate>          
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
    ...
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The DeleteMethod `ListView1_DeleteItem`:

```
public void ListView1_DeleteItem(int id)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The id of button is: " + id);
  using (var db = new NotesContext())
  {
    var note = (from n in db.Notes
                   where n.NoteId == id
                   select n).Single();       
    db.Notes.Remove(note);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

If I look in browser console I see this exception rising:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: A null value for
>   parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void
>   ListView1_DeleteItem(Int32)' in 'NotesPractice._Default'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type or a nullable type.

This suggests that the `NoteId` value (which is specified in the [DataKeyNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx)) is not reaching the delete method, thus it's throwing the exception. Why isn't any data reaching the method?

I also tried explicitly specifying the DataKeyNames with no luck:

```
DataKeyNames="NotesPractice.Note.NoteId"
```

Here is a copy of my database:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Delete method like this:-

```
public void ListView1_DeleteItem(int NoteId)
```

Model Binding feature requires this as per the design.

> The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the
>   control

Check [Dan Wahlin's](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding) blog for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm actually out on my lunch break, will check this out soon as I'm back!

Comment: +1 thank you so much, works perfectly! I would never have guessed the parameter was causing the issue! Thanks for the link to the blog as well, I look forward reading it :)

Comment: @gudthing - Glad to help you :)